# moltenvk project makefile- how to link via clang

Tags: xcode, macos, clang, metal, vulkan

This file: [MoltenVK  Runtime User Guide](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK/blob/master/Docs/MoltenVK_Runtime_UserGuide.md#install) offers a nice description of how to link MoltenVK to a project that uses it, within XCode.

I prefer using makefiles, as it removes the need to boot up XCode to build (+ is a consistent workflow with the same project on Linux).

The problem is there's quite a bit of OSX/XCode specific terminology in the instructions, and I'm not quite sure how it translates to running `clang` via command line.

If you assume I'm looking to link only with the minimum specified to use MoltenVK, **what would such a command line argument look like?**

Here is my minimal attempt:

```
MOLTENVKDIR = /blah/vulkansdk-macos-1.1.108.0

a.out: my_headers.h my_src_files.cpp
    clang -I$(MOLTENVKDIR)/MoltenVK/include -L$(MOLTENVKDIR)/MoltenVK/macOS/dynamic -lMoltenVK my_src_files.cpp
```

More specific questions:

How should I be setting `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS`? I assume this is a `PATH`-style variable that gets embedded in the executable with a list of places to look for the `MoltenVK.dylib` file?

In step 4 of the user guide, it says "*drag (MoltenVK/macOS/dynamic/libMoltenVK.dylib) to the Link Binary With Libraries list*"- is that essentially the `-lMoltenVK` line?

Where does step 5 come in? Should I append `-framework Metal -framework Foundation -framework ...`? What should I do with the `.tbd` file?

Is step 6 just ensuring that I copy the `libMoltenVK.dylib` file relative to `a.out` consistent with `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS`?

Is step 7 safe to ignore, as I'm not using XCode?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; I use g++, use the flags `-lMoltenVK` and `-L$(MOLTENVK_DIR)`, and at the top define `VK_ICD_FILENAMES` using `export VK_ICD_FILENAMES=$(ICD_DIR)`

Header Search Paths is `-I$(PATH)`
Library Search Paths is `-L$(PATH)`
Runpath Search Paths is `-rpath $(PATH)` (with the space)

What I did was copy the .dylibs into a folder called `lib` in my project folder, set Library Search Path with `-Llib`, and link them with `-lvulkan` and `-lMoltenVK`. Since these dynamic libraries are hardwired to use @rpath when linking, I set `-rpath lib`.

You can see the [vulkan tutorial for linux which uses a Makefile](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment#page_Setting-up-a-makefile-project) which shows a very basic version of making a Makefile for Vulkan on linux (no MoltenVK)

**Most importantly, to not get a VkResult -9 when calling vkCreateInstance (MoltenVK not installed properly) make sure to define the `VK_ICD_FILENAMES` environment variable!** I did this by writing `export VK_ICD_FILENAMES=lib/MoltenVK_icd.json` near the top of my Makefile, and **copied the `MoltenVK_icd.json` file to my project!** This is a file which points to where the dylib is, and is necesarry for MoltenVK to work. When installing MoltenVK, it was inside the same folder as libMoltenVK.dylib

Similarily, you must define `VK_LAYER_PATH` for validation layers to work.
Minimally, all you need for MoltenVK is:

```
export VK_ICD_FILENAMES=lib/MoltenVK_icd.json 
main:
    g++ test.cpp -o App -Llib -rpath lib -lMoltenVK
```

I'm not an expert in best practices and conventions, I do what works. Hope this helped